# View Content of iPhone's Web Storage Database

Tags: database, cordova, web-storage

It seems like there isn't anything on the web on this. In Android I can access the database file by browsing the filesystem in *Logcat*. However, I don't know how to view the content of my database on iPhone, which is populated using the [Phonegap Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html).

Since the question doesn't contain any code, it would be kind to tell me where to ask the question if I may be wrong here.

Thanks a lot for your time.